# What's the difference between "hätten" und "wären" in konjunktiv II?

Tags: subjunctive, auxiliary-verb

I've been learning about K2 and I'm confused about the difference between "hätten" und "wären". They seem to have the same meaning.

Z.B.

> Wir **wären** gern im Zoo.
> Wir **hätten** gern im Zoo.

and

> Du **hättest** gern weniger Stress gehabt.
> Du **wärst** gern weniger Stress gehabt.

Comment: It is probably helpful to explain your confusion with some examples.

Comment: They are, respectively, Konjunktiv 2 conjugations of »haben« (to have) and »sein« (to be). What makes you think those words have the same meaning? From your examples only the very first one »Wir wären gern im Zoo.« is a correct sentence.

Comment: because in english both are past tense.

Comment: Your examples are seriously flawed: Just the first is example is a correct sentence. Without adjustment this question is likely to be closed for being unclear.

Comment: @Gustyani: please include your reason for "have the same meaning" into your question. "past tense" seems to broad for me, because I remember several pasts my teacher tried to teach me back then.

Answer (score 7):

In short:

- "hätten" = Konjunktiv von "haben" = "to have" in english
- "wären" = Konjunktiv von "sein" = "to be" in english

To your examples:

- "Wir wären gern im Zoo" translates to "We would like to be in the zoo"
- "Wir hätten gern im Zoo" is not a complete german sentence, similar to ""We would like to have in the zoo" not being a complete english sentence.

So I guess the difference in meaning is better understood by not focussing on the Konjunktiv - the difference is already there in the infinitive.

Answer (score -3):

There is no difference. Using "sein" vs. "haben" with certain verbs is pure inflection; there is no more meaning behind this alternation than between the alternation of gender, e.g. "masculine" for "Tisch" vs. "feminine" for "Tür".

Comment: You should probably clarify that you're only refering to the difference between "haben" and "sein" as the modal verb for *Konjunktiv 2 perfect tense*. Which might be the heart of the question, but there's so much more that would have to be explained, especially since the incorrect examples show some wider lack of understanding.

Comment: @HalvarF It's not our aim to explain that some sentence is incorrect. That would be proof-reading.

Comment: @c.p.: Answering this question with "There is no difference" is just plain wrong, especially when the OP doesn't seem to understand that they can only use either sein or haben with a given verb. These sentences are obiously examples, discussing them has nothing to do with proofreading imo.

Comment: @c.p. But the other answer is pretty good, while giving an explanation why one of the sentences is incorrect. I don't see how language learners can ask questions at all if a wrong example automatically disqualified their questions. OP does not seem to have been aware that one of their sentences is incorrect, therefore there is certainly no request for proofreading involved.

Comment: @DavidVogt Another answer should not motivate two downvotes on this, just because the other is better :-) That's my point. It could be that this answer not providing the corrections motivated the downvotes. But the other was already written, so I don't see the point in repeating that information.

Comment: Opinions and ambiguous meditations aside, this doesn't answer the question and to say that there's no difference between "to be in the zoo" and "to have in the zoo" is incorrect and motivates my downvote. Unfortunately downvoting damages the downvoter, but I can't understand how this unreflected stuff can be upvoted. This is a very concrete case that has a concrete answer.